# What's the differences between the Herniated discs and Cervical spondylitis with cord/root compression?

Tags: spine

[image]
[image]
For the first picture, it shows the Herniated discs and the second picture shows the cervical spondylitis.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Also, you need to provide a link to the source of those images.

Answer (score 3):

A **herniated disc** means that a part of a disc has ruptured and squeezed out beyond its regular circumference. A herniated disc may or may not press upon the spinal cord or a root of a spinal nerve.

**Spondylosis** refers to *age-related wear and tear* of the spinal discs, which is the most common cause of a herniated disc. [**Cervical spondylosis**](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/cervical-spondylosis/symptoms-causes/syc-20370787) means that the neck (Latin: cervix) part of the spine is affected.

[**Spondylitis**](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/ankylosing-spondylitis/symptoms-causes/syc-20354808) refers to an *inflammatory disease* of the spine. Like in spondylosis, the parts of damaged discs or vertebra can result in nerve root compression. The most common changes in spondylitis are bone spurs and fusion of the vertebra (ankylosis) but less likely herniated discs.

The top picture shows a herniated disc, probably due to spondylosis. The bottom picture also shows a herniated disc, probably due to spondylitis (because the right arrow shows that some vertebral bone is affected).